# How to convert each line of text on the same cell to hyperlinks , Excel vba?

Tags: excel, vba

How to convert each line of text on the same cell to hyperlinks ?

the below code works correctly if cells has only one line of text !

**Note**: any workarounds is accepted.

```
Sub Convert_To_Hyperlinks()

  Dim Rng As Range
  Dim WorkRng As Range
  Dim LastRow As Long
  Dim ws As Worksheet
   
  Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
  Set WorkRng = ws.Range("N2", ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp))

  For Each Rng In WorkRng
  Application.ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Rng, Rng.Value
  Next Rng
  
End Sub
```

Comment: No can do. A cell in Excel can only have one hyperlink. You cannot have multiple hyperlinks in one cell.

Comment: @teyln. is there any workaround , even change texts to shapes with hyperlinks

Comment: You could use shapes as a workaround. If you set the background and border to "transparent", the text within could be a hyperlink. The cell "behind" the shape would have to be resized to "contain" however many links/shapes needed and those shapes arranged in a way that they would not overlap and each shape/link is selectable. It's a workaround, but non-trivial because of all the alignments and resizing that would need to happen.

Comment: @PeterT. is it possible to split cells with multi lines to adjacent cells and converts to hyperlinks afterwards , I am little experienced with vba.

Comment: You can look at creating multiple rows, one for each hyperlink. In this case you would repeat the same work order number -- this is my recommended solution, for many reasons. Another possibility is to create those multiple rows, and then merge all the cells in column A with the same work order value.  But there are [problems when](https://edu.gcfglobal.org/en/excel-tips/why-you-should-avoid-merging-cells/1/) [merging cells](https://itstraining.wichita.edu/excel-dont-merge-those-cells-here-is-an-alternative/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Excel allows only one hyperlink per cell. So, in order to do what you need, a workaround should be necessary. I would propose adding text boxes over each cell, placing the hyperlink text in them and add hyperlink to each text box.

Please, test the next code:

```
Sub testHyperlinkUsingShapes()
   Dim sh As Worksheet, s As Shape, arrH, cHyp As Range, sHeight As Double
   Dim rngHyp As Range, sWidth As Double, relTop As Double, i As Long
   
    Set sh = ActiveSheet
    Set rngHyp = sh.Range("N2:N" & sh.Range("N" & sh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

    'a little optimization to make the code faster:
    Application.EnableEvents = False: Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    deleteTextBoxes 'for the case when you need repeating the process (if manually changed some cells hyperling strings)
    For Each cHyp In rngHyp.Cells 'iterate between cells of the range to be processed
        If cHyp.Value <> "" Then  'process only not empty cells
            arrH = filterSimilarH(cHyp) '1D array 1 based af unique hyperlink strings...
            sHeight = cHyp.Height / UBound(arrH) 'set the height of the text boxes to be created
            sWidth = cHyp.Width 'the same for the with
            For i = 1 To UBound(arrH) 'for each found (unique) hyperlink strings:
                'create a text box with dimensions set above
                Set s = sh.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, cHyp.Left, cHyp.Top + relTop, sWidth, sHeight)
                sh.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=s, Address:=arrH(i) 'add hyperlink address
                With s
                    .TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = arrH(i) 'place the hyperlink string as the text box text
                    .TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = cHyp.Font.Size 'match the font size with the cell one
                    .TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Name = cHyp.Font.Name 'match the font type with the cell one
                    .TextFrame2.VerticalAnchor = msoAnchorMiddle 'center the text
                    .Line.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorText1 'match the border line coloor with the cell one
                    .Placement = xlMoveAndSize
                End With
                s.Hyperlink.Address = arrH(i) 'set the hyperlink address
                relTop = relTop + sHeight 'adapt the Top position for the next text box to be places in the same cell
            Next i
            relTop = 0 'reinitialize the top for the next cell
        End If
    Next
    Application.EnableEvents = True: Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "Ready..."
End Sub

Sub deleteTextBoxes() 'delete the existing text boxes, if any
   Dim s As Shape
   For Each s In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        If s.Type = msoTextBox Then
            If s.TopLeftCell.Column = 14 Then
                s.Delete
            End If
        End If
   Next
End Sub

Function filterSimilarH(rngCel As Range) As Variant
  Dim arr, uniques: arr = Split(rngCel.Value, vbLf) 'keep only unique hyperlinks, if duplicates exist
  
  With Application
      uniques = .Index(arr, 1, Filter(.IfError(.Match(.Transpose(.Evaluate("ROW(1:" & _
                  UBound(.Match(arr, arr, 0)) & ")")), .Match(arr, arr, 0), 0), "|"), "|", False))
  End With
   filterSimilarH = uniques
End Function
```

Comment: it works with these notes: (1) it will be great from you to adopt code to delete duplicates ( Per each cell and not whole column ) , (2) is it possible if text box has border like real cell , this will be fantastic

Comment: @Waleed_wwm 1. It should be possible. 2. Not sure I understood what you mean. If this means that **each text box** to have the border like the real cell, I think it should be possible (not sure, because the `Line` property of the text box is not the same with the cell border weight). If you want **only the perimeter to have the same border**, it is not possible. You cannot set different text box border properties for left, right, bottom or top, like in case of a cell...

Comment: @Waleed_wwm Adapted the code to filter the unique hyperlink strings.

Comment: @Waleed_wwm Updated the code to also create the same text border as the cells one.

Comment: @FaneDure Excellent Woks , All is fine now and many great special thanks for all your help and support

Comment: Could you add some comments on the code ?

Comment: @Soma I thought it shouldn't be difficult to understand it. Added comments on more of the code lines...

Answer (score 4):

As told by others,  in one cell you can have only one hyperlink.

**Note**: You have in some cells the same attachment name duplicated!

I quote what you said "is it possible to split cells with multi lines to adjacent cells and converts to hyperlinks afterwards", so this code might do what you need.

```
Sub Convert_To_Hyperlinks()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim WorkRng As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim lastCol As Long
    Dim arrStr() As String
     
    Set WorkRng = ws.Range("N2", ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp))
    
    For Each rng In WorkRng
        ' find last column for current row
        lastCol = ws.Cells(rng.Row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        
        If InStr(1, rng.Value, Chr(10)) > 0 Then
            ' multiple attachments: split text into array
            arrStr = Split(rng.Value, Chr(10))
            
            ' copy array after last column
            Cells(rng.Row, lastCol + 1).Resize(1, UBound(arrStr) - LBound(arrStr) + 1) = arrStr
            
            ' create hyperlink
            For i = LBound(arrStr) To UBound(arrStr)
                Application.ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Cells(rng.Row, lastCol + 1 + i), arrStr(i)
            Next i
        
        ElseIf rng.Value <> "" Then
            ' only one attachment: copy range value after last column
            Cells(rng.Row, lastCol + 1).Value = rng.Value
            
            ' create hyperlink
            Application.ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Cells(rng.Row, lastCol + 1), rng.Value
        End If
    Next rng
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for your efforts , your answer works also , But other answer by "FaneDure" is convenient to my work needs .